# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I'm trying to use TO_LOB() func to resolve problem with LONG type. But something goes wrong and i got this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

There is sql query with which I want to select some information about the columns in my DB.

```
SELECT
  cols.table_name, 
  cols.column_name, 
  TO_LOB(cols.data_default) AS data_by_default,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cols.nullable = 'N' OR cons.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS is_required,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cons.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS is_primary_key,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cons.constraint_type = 'R' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS is_foreign_key,
  comm.comments
FROM user_tab_columns cols
LEFT JOIN user_cons_columns cons_cols
  ON cols.table_name = cons_cols.table_name
  AND cols.column_name = cons_cols.column_name
LEFT JOIN user_constraints cons
  ON cons_cols.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name
LEFT JOIN user_col_comments comm
  ON cols.table_name = comm.table_name
  AND cols.column_name = comm.column_name
GROUP BY cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.data_default, cols.data_length, cols.nullable, comm.comments
ORDER BY cols.table_name;
```

Comment: Please provide your table DDL (in the form of CREATE TABLE statements), DML to create sample data (INSERT INTO), and the results you want to obtain from that data.

Comment: Sure you want to GROUP BY cols.data_length and cols.nullable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F), `long` column cannot be part of any expression in a standalone `select` statement.

One of possible ways to overcome this restriction in SQL statement is to wrap an access to such table with `dbms_xmlgen` functions, which will serialize `long` column values into XML that may be consumed by `XMLTable` function.

Setup:

```
create table t (
  id int generated always as identity,
  val int default 0
)
```

Any expression with `long` fails:

```
select
  cols.table_name, 
  cols.column_name, 
  'default: ' || cols.data_default AS data_by_default
from user_tab_cols cols
```

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
```

But it may be serialized in XML:

```
select
  cols.table_name, 
  cols.column_name, 
  'default: ' || cols.data_default AS data_by_default
from xmltable(
  '/ROWSET/ROW'
  passing dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(
    'select
       table_name,
       column_name,
       data_default
     from user_tab_cols'
  )
  columns
    table_name varchar2(128),
    column_name varchar2(128),
    data_default clob
) cols
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_BY_DEFAULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T | ID | default: "FIDDLE_HIMLSTYQCBPASLVRNFQB"."ISEQ$$_159803".nextval |
| T | VAL | default: 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1Ljk2XrJ)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot work with LONGs like that... they will not convert to CLOB in that way. You have to assign them in PL/SQL. If the values are less than 32K in length, it's really easy:

```
DECLARE
  var_default varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR rec_default IN (SELECT data_default
                        FROM user_tab_columns)
  LOOP
    var_default := rec_default.data_default;
    -- you now have a varchar2 version of your long value.
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I've written an enriched set of dictionary views for our databases, and one of the things these do is get rid of LONGs. Here's my dba_tab_columns extension:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dba_tab_columns_ext(in_owner IN varchar2, in_table_name IN varchar2, in_column_Name IN varchar2)
  RETURN varchar2
AS
  var_my_feature_name feature.feature_name%TYPE := 'Enhanced Dictionary Views';
  not_enabled exception;
  var_data_default varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  IF NOT f_feature_enabled(var_my_feature_name)
  THEN
    RAISE not_enabled;
  END IF;
  
  FOR rec_expr IN (SELECT *
                     FROM dba_tab_columns
                    WHERE owner = in_owner
                      AND table_name = in_table_name
                      AND column_name = in_column_name)
  LOOP
    var_data_default := rec_expr.data_default;
  END LOOP;
  
  RETURN var_data_default;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN not_enabled THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'The Enhanced Dictionary Views feature is disabled');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_log_unified_error(var_my_feature_name,'in_owner = '||in_owner||', in_table_name = '||in_table_name||', in_column_Name = '||in_column_Name);
    RAISE;
END;  
/

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dba_tab_columns_ext
AS
SELECT owner,
        table_name,
        column_name,
        data_type,
        data_type_mod,
        data_type_owner,
        data_length,
        data_precision,
        data_scale,
        nullable,
        column_id,
        default_length,
        f_dba_tab_columns_ext(owner,table_name,column_name) AS data_default,
        num_distinct,
        low_value,
        high_value,
        cast_raw_to_display_string(low_value,data_type) low_value_display,
        cast_raw_to_display_string(high_value,data_type) high_value_display,
        density,
        num_nulls,
        num_buckets,
        last_analyzed,
        sample_size,
        character_set_name,
        char_col_decl_length,
        global_stats,
        user_stats,
        avg_col_len,
        char_length,
        char_used,
        v80_fmt_image,
        data_upgraded,
        histogram,
        default_on_null,
        identity_column,
        sensitive_column,
        evaluation_edition,
        unusable_before,
        unusable_beginning,
        collation
  FROM dba_tab_columns
 ORDER BY owner,table_name,column_id
```

You get the idea.  If, however, you have to do this with dba_views.text, or dba_triggers.trigger_body or some other LONG that exceeds 4000 chars (if you need it in SQL) or 32767 char (if you need it only in PL/SQL), then you would unfortunatley have to use the `dbms_sql.column_value_long` procedure, which would require a rather lengthy and complex configuration of a `dbms_sql` cursor, and iteration on the `dbms_sql.column_value_long` until the full value is pulled, appending to a temporary CLOB as you go. That should not be required however for shorter LONGs like dba_columns.data_default, dba_tab_partitions.high_value, etc.. forget trying to get those into CLOB and just go with a varchar2(4000) output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use sys_dburigen and decide the size you want to extract from the CLOB:

```
SELECT
  cols.table_name, 
  cols.column_name, 
  cols.data_default,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cols.nullable = 'N' OR cons.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS is_required,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cons.constraint_type = 'P' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS is_primary_key,
  MAX(CASE WHEN cons.constraint_type = 'R' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS is_foreign_key,
  comm.comments
FROM (select table_name, column_name, nullable, data_length,
    dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(table_name, column_name, column_id, data_default, 'text()').getclob(),1,256) AS data_default
    from user_tab_columns) cols
LEFT JOIN user_cons_columns cons_cols
  ON cols.table_name = cons_cols.table_name
  AND cols.column_name = cons_cols.column_name
LEFT JOIN user_constraints cons
  ON cons_cols.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name
LEFT JOIN user_col_comments comm
  ON cols.table_name = comm.table_name
  AND cols.column_name = comm.column_name
GROUP BY cols.table_name, cols.column_name, 
    cols.data_default, cols.data_length, cols.nullable, comm.comments
ORDER BY cols.table_name;
```